# Difference between pytz.UTC and pytz.timezone('GMT')

Tags: pytz

pytz's [documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#problems-with-localtime) says:

> Note that this instance [pytz.timezone('UTC')] is not the same instance (or implementation)
>   as other timezones with the same meaning (GMT, Greenwich, Universal,
>   etc.).

and indeed:

```
>>> pytz.timezone('UTC') is pytz.timezone('GMT')
False
```

So... what's the difference?
When should I use `pytz.timezone('UTC')` and when should I use `pytz.timezone('GMT')`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The UTC implementation is a tzinfo implementation that will at all times return 0 minutes offset.

The timezone you get when you do pytz.timezone('GMT') is the GMT timezone defined in the Olson database. It also will return 0 at all times, but in a more complicated manner.

Use UTC.

Comment: [...But GMT is a time zone and UTC is a time standard.](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html)

Comment: No, they are both time standards. "Time zones" don't really exist.

Comment: Timezones that may have a UTC+00:00 offset at some point include Europe/London, Europe/Lisbon, Africa/Bissau, Atlantic/Reykjavik, Etc/UTC, Etc/GMT